Ingress controller ssl - the certificate verification probably failed
I am trying to setup ssl certificates for my ingress controller.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sample-app-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.ingress-tls.com
    secretName: ingress-cert
  rules:
  - host: "www.ingress-tls.com"
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: sample-app-service
              port:
                number: 80

any my tls
NAME                      TYPE                DATA   AGE
ingress-cert              kubernetes.io/tls   2      10m
ingress-nginx-admission   Opaque              3      18m

but my curl returns following error -
curl -vvI https://www.ingress-tls.com
* About to connect() to www.ingress-tls.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.218.149.28...
* Connected to www.ingress-tls.com (10.218.149.28) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*       subject: E=some@gmail.com,CN=www.ingress-tls.com,OU=test,O=test,L=Cal,ST=CA,C=US
*       start date: Sep 06 14:08:46 2024 GMT
*       expire date: Jan 22 14:08:46 2052 GMT
*       common name: www.ingress-tls.com
*       issuer: E=some@gmail.com,CN=www.ingress-tls.com,OU=test,O=test,L=Cal,ST=CA,C=US
* NSS error -8172 (SEC_ERROR_UNTRUSTED_ISSUER)
* Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

I have tried different things, but still no luck . any help ??
I am currently using GKE cluster.

This would be better asked on ServerFault.

"I have tried different things, but still no luck" - this sentence provides zero relevant information about what you actually did. Either delete it or provide actual information instead.
